# Finding the number of intensive care babies using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11gr2

I have a BIGTABLE:

```
 | name |surname| date_of_birth |hospital| op_id | op_date | medical_branch | 
 |++++++|+++++++|+++++++++++++++|++++++++|+++++++|+++++++++|++++++++++++++++|
 |      |       |               |        |       |         |                |
```

It is a table with records of medical operations in about 500 hospitals for a year. There are about 300 million rows.

**My question is:**

**For every Hospital X, how many babies were born and how many of them got intensive care immediately (same day) after birth on the same hospital?**

For example in hospital A, 100 babies were born and 20 of them were taken to intensive care on the very same day in the same hospital.

**P619920 is the operation id for birth.** Id info of the mother is recorded for birth, not the baby.

**I552015 is the operation id for intensive care.** Id info of the baby is recorded.

First, I isolated hospital A by:

```
create table hospital_A as ( select * from BIGTABLE where hospital = 'A' )
```

Pattern of hospital_A is like:

```
| name  |surname| date_of_birth|hospital| op_id |  op_date  |  medical_branch  | 
|+++++++|+++++++|++++++++++++++|++++++++|+++++++|+++++++++++|+++++++++++++++++ |
| Mary  | White |  01.02.1981  |   A    |P619920| 09.12.2011|   Gynecology     |
| John  | White |  09.12.2011  |   A    |I552015| 09.12.2011|Infantile diseases|
```

I tried to match :

a) surnames of the baby and mother

b) the operation dates.

```
select distinct
 t.name
,t.surname
,t.op_date
,t.op_id
,t.medical_branch
,v.name
,v.surname
--,v.op_id
,v.medical_branch
,v.date_of_birth
,v.hospital
from hospital_A t, hospital_A v
where t.op_date=v.date_of_birth
and t.surname=v.surname
and t.op_id = 'P619920'
and v.op_id = 'I552015'
```

This gave me 20 rows.

Bu when I apply the same query to BIGTABLE, there are 81 rows for Hospital A.

I understand this difference stems from babies which were born in other hospitals but were taken to Hospital A on the same day for intensive care.

In the BIGTABLE, pattern is like:

```
| name  |surname|date_of_birth|hospital|  op_id  | op_date  |  medical_branch  | 
|+++++++|+++++++|+++++++++++++|++++++++|+++++++++|++++++++++|++++++++++++++++++|
| Mary  | White | 01.02.1981  |   A    | P619920 |09.10.2011|   Gynecology     |
| John  | White | 09.10.2011  |   A    | I552015 |09.10.2011|Infantile diseases|
| Ellen | Young | 04.09.1978  |   B    | P619920 |07.12.2011|   Gynecology     |
| Robert| Young | 07.12.2011  |   A    | I552015 |07.12.2011|Infantile diseases|
```

So, the results of the BIGTABLE is different from the isolated hospital_A table, as it  contains Hospital B.

My query for BIGTABLE should extract the **same day birth-intensive care combination which happened in the same hospital.**

The resulting table:

```
 | hospital | total births | intensive_care_babies |
 |----------|--------------|-----------------------|
 |     A    |     100      |        20             |
 |     B    |     ...      |        ..             |
```

Comment: Isn't there any better connection between mother and baby? Using the name as a matching criterion is pretty bad, because the last name is not unique. There can be several mothers with the same last name at the same time.

Comment: you should change your title, because we might be expert in sql, but not in hospital stuff...

Comment: I guess in quite a lot of (western?) countries it's even plain wrong. I know of only 1 child in my entire friends-list where a baby was given the same surname as her mother [because there was no 'official' father]; in all other cases it's the fathers surname that's being used so the query in its current form would filter out 99% of all cases. Simply relying on date_of_birth = op_date (and in the same hospital?) wouldn't be perfect yet but still MUCH closer to the truth I guess.

Comment: It seems that there is no perfect link between mothers and babies  ( and what about twins? what about no name given yet? ) in this table. Another issue would be notion of "same day" -  is midnight sharp border? Birt at 23:55 and intensive care at 0:05 would not qualify as same day?

Comment: Using name for matching is not perfect, however it gives reasonable amount of result and it is the best option available. And time is not important as the medical operations are not recorded simultaneously but at the end of the following day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply append the condition that both rows must be from the same hospital:

```
and t.hospital = v.hospital
```

BTW, you are missing one more condition in your statement. You are checking that the OP date of the mother is the same as the birth date of the baby. You are using this to match the baby to its mother. But you forgot to check that the OP date of the baby is the same as its birth date. This condition is required to get only the babies that are sent to intensive care on the day they were born.

---

To answer the question in your comment:

```
select
    b.hospital,
    count(b.surname) as total_births,
    count(i.surname) as intensive_care_babies,
from
    bigtable b,
    left outer join bigtable i
      on  b.surname = i.surname
      and b.op_date = i.date_of_birth
      and b.op_id = 'P619920'
      and i.op_id = 'I552015'
      and b.hospital = i.hospital
group by
    b.hospital
;
```

Comment: Good point.How to find the number of total births and number of intensive care in single query?

Comment: I tried it on a sample table with 750000 rows but execution plan got crazy. [Here it is.](http://pastebin.com/b63HVvq9)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, surname, hospital, op_date
  FROM BIGTABLE
 WHERE op_id = 'P619920'
INTERSECT
SELECT name, surname, hospital, op_date
  FROM BIGTABLE
 WHERE op_id = 'I552015';
```

Comment: What's that supposed to do? Note: Name of the mother is not the same as name of the baby.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to hospital, join on name in addition to surname, or better yet, on a person-id if you have it. With this many rows, there are almost guaranteed to be persons with identical names and surnames.

Comment: Joining on name will not work, because the name of the mother is different from that of the baby.

Comment: Ah, thinko on my part - thanks. But joining on surname only will certainly give you some false positives in any large hospital. Probably nothing to be done about that, if there is no explicit mother-child relationship available. (BTW, in Germany the surname of child == surname of mother assumption would often be wrong).

Comment: I agree with you about this problem and already raised this issue in a comment to the question. :)